# Backpack (morph) relationship field add condition to prevent fail if class doesn't exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

So here's my relation:

```
Class Log extends Model {
    
    public function entity()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

in my other classes:

```
Class User extends Model{
        
    public function log()
    {
       return $this->morphOne(Log::class, 'entity');
    }   
}
```

This works just as expected, for eg. if entity_type is User and entity_id is 14, it will give me User with id 14. Problem comes when the entity_type is simple SYSTEM and entity_id is null (Sadly I can't change this). Normally if it wouldn't be Backpack I'd only go

```
$log->entity_id ? $log->entity->name : '';
```

But in Backpack I've failed to achieve this. Tried this though:

```
[
    'name' => 'entity',
    'label' => __('logs.entity_name'),
    'type' => 'relationship',
    'attribute' => 'name',
    'options' => (function($query){
        return $query->whereNotNull('entity_id')->get();
    })
],
```

But this does not work. Any suggestion how could I achieve the same result for my field as I could in a blade file with the ternary I've shown is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to work out, here's my solution :

```
[
  'label' => __('logs.entity_name'),
  'type' => 'closure',
  'function' => function ($entry) {
     if ($entry->entity_id == null) {
         return $entry->entity_type;
     }
         try {
             return $entry->entity->name;
         } catch (\Exception $e) {
             return '';
           }
     },
],
```